# How to find the median in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a single table that houses student scores by their classes.
For example, each class has 30 students, so there are 30 scores for each class.
I'd like to do a simple report that averages, does a median, and a mode, for each data set per class.
So, each class will have an average, a median, and a mode.
I know that SQL Server does not have a built in function for median and mode, and I found sample SQLs for the median. However, the samples I found do not do any grouping, I found:

```
SELECT
(
 (SELECT MAX(Value) FROM
   (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Value FROM dbo.VOrders ORDER BY Value) AS H1)
 +
 (SELECT MIN(Value) FROM
   (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Value FROM dbo.VOrders ORDER BY Value DESC) AS H2)
) / 2 AS Median
```

Is it possible to modify to add a group by so I get a median value per class?

---

i don;t think i was clear enough, i'd like the SQL to return one data set, looking something like this:

```
MEDIAN CLASS 
====== ===== 
 90     BIO 
 77     CHEM
```

Comment: Please show us your data schema, almost impossible to help without it.

Comment: Table Name: ALL_SCORES
Fields: id, studentName, score, class
Example data:
    1, homer, 100, BIO
2, marge, 90, BIO
3, bart, 85, BIO
4, lisa, 100, CHEM
5, henry, 55, CHEM
6, jed, 77, CHEM

For each class, would like the stats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT e_id, 
   scale, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e_id ORDER BY scale ASC) AS rn,   
   COUNT(scale) OVER(PARTITION BY e_id) AS cn
FROM waypoint.dbo.ScoreMaster
WHERE scale IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT e_id,

cast(AVG (cast(scale as decimal(5,2))) as decimal(5,3)) as [AVG],
cast (STDEV(cast(scale as decimal(5,1))) as decimal(5,3)) as [STDDEV],   
AVG(CASE WHEN 2 * rn - cn BETWEEN 0 AND 2 THEN scale END) AS FinancialMedian,
MAX(CASE WHEN 2 * rn - cn BETWEEN 0 AND 2 THEN scale END) AS StatisticalMedian

from CTE
GROUP BY e_id
```